# Merge cells if value of other cell is the same

Tags: excel

I have a table with orders products and amounts. I want to merge the data of amount if the productID is a duplicate in the same order.

Is there a formula that can achieve this?

[image: Excel data]

In OrderID = 1 ProductID=5 is there 4 times with the value 14,27,20 and 5. how do I end up with one cell with the amount 66.

Comment: Why don't you use Pivot table ?

Comment: What do you mean "merge", "sum"?